# Equivalent to like in XQuery?

Tags: sql, xquery, xquery-sql

I am trying to get all titles that contain a certain word from my database in XQuery in SQL I would use `WHERE title LIKE '%England%'` - I am wondering how to do this in XQuery?

My XQuery query looks like this:

```
(:Selects document:)
for $x in doc ("tmdb_5000_movies(1).xml")/movies/movie 
(: :)
where $x/title (:NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE:)
(:0:)
return $x/ *
```

Comment: Does this line of code do the same as like? for $x in doc ("tmdb_5000_movies(1).xml")/movies/movie [matches(title, '.*England')] 

(:0:)
return $x/ *

Answer (score 1):

This does it.

```
for $x in doc ("tmdb_5000_movies(1).xml")/movies/movie [matches(title, '.*England')] 

return $x/ *
```

Much prefer SQL, However, I can see why this is the future

Answer (score 1):

I have no SQL DB to test with at hand but

```
doc("movies.xml")//movie[matches(title, '^.*England.*$')]/*
```

does work in other xquery runtimes. You should test, if you need the FLOWR-expression.

The regular expression @BradleighJL uses in his answer could be faster (`.*England`) and should also match all the cases. I just wanted to make a distinction between just "%England" (`'^.*England$'`) and `%England%`.